# Programmatically change the src attribute on embed player Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, embed

I am trying to change the src attribute to play a youtube video within javascript but cannot seem to get it to work.

Here is the statement I have been trying to use:

```
$("#youtube-player").setAttribute('src', obj[i].SongURL);
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="youtube-player">
     <embed id="player" width="420" height="345"
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
</div>
```

obj[i] has the correct data FYI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are changing src in wrong `id`

```
$("#player").attr('src', obj[i].SongURL);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the src attribute of a div not the embed tag try the following.

```
$("#youtube-player > embed").attr('src', obj[i].SongURL);
```

or better yet select `#player` like @LOL suggests above :P

[Demo width video tag](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/V4uhQ/)

Comment: I have to wait 9 mins to mark the answer by the way haha